# Convert String To Date

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to convert `dd/MM/yyyy` to `MM/dd/yyyy`.

My code:

```
string g = "20-1-1999";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(g, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Error Message:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give single `M` for month in format string. You can read more about format specifier MM, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MM_Specifier) and M [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#M_Specifier). You also need to using `-` as separator instead of `/`

```
DateTime.ParseExact(g, "dd-M-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you expect day single digit you would give single `d` for day too.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(g, "d-M-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

#### The "MM" Custom Format Specifier

> The "MM" custom format specifier represents the month as a number from
>   01 through 12 (or from 1 through 13 for calendars that have 13
>   months). A single-digit month is formatted with a leading zero, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MM_Specifier)

#### The "M" Custom Format Specifier

> The "M" custom format specifier represents the month as a number from
>   1 through 12 (or from 1 through 13 for calendars that have 13 months).
>   A single-digit month is formatted without a leading zero, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#M_Specifier).

Answer (score 2):

your format should be `dd-M-yyyy`

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(g, "dd-M-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var result = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```